# I am trying to switch out an object in a char array with a string

Tags: c++

Hi I have an assignment in my class and I wanted to spice it up with a leader board that is inside of an array that I than print and store in a text file. Obviously it hasn't worked because every time I run then check the text file, it's the same and the array didn't change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  FILE *filePr;

  filePr = fopen("example.txt", "w");
  char lang[3][100] = {"Auden", "James", "Gibson"};
  int score[3] = {12, 9, 3};

  int userScore = 12;
  string userName = "aud";

  for (int g = 0; g < 3; g++){
    if (userScore > score[g]){
      userName = lang[g];
      userScore = score[g];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    fprintf(filePr, "Score and name %s %i\n", lang[i], score[i]);
  }
  fclose(filePr);
  cout << "Code has finished running";
}
```

I have tried everything and nothing will work, please help.

I wanted the file to update with the new name and score, but it didn't.

Comment: Don't do parallel arrays.  Create a structure with name (std::string) and score members.  The create `std::vector` or `std::array` of the structure.  A lot easier to develop and maintain.

Comment: The user's name and score are being overwritten with the values in the array, not the other way around. Then when the array is written to the file it contains the initial values. because the array was never altered.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ serialization".  Writing objects to a file and reading them from a file falls under the category of *serialization*.

Comment: The program goes to some trouble to compute `userName` and `userScore`, but then doesn't actually use them for anything. Did you mean to write them to the file or something?

Comment: A problem like this is easy fodder for a debugger. Run the program in the debugger, then step through the program line by line until you see the program do something you didn't expect like store the wrong value (not store it in this case) or take the wrong path. That'll be a bug, so stop and examine the line more closely.

Comment: If this is the style of code you have been taught, you have not been taught c++. You will have a hard time finding suitable answers. I'll probably do a short writeup in a few minutes to simplify things for you a bit.

Comment: So you wrote `userName = lang[g]; userScore = score[g];` but that is backwards.  You cannot write `lang[g] = userName; score[g] = userScore;` because you can't copy a string to a array of characters.  So you need to write `strcpy(lang[g],userName.c_str()); score[g] = userScore;`  https://onlinegdb.com/2uxjXuNzl

Comment: Unrelated side notes: `using namespace std;` is an antipattern, just don’t do that. Other than that your code is C, not C++ (`std::string` and `std::cout` aside), and you [may have a bad teacher](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk?si=1rPSD3rMnuznp7hz).

Answer (score 2):

Your have been taught "C" not "C++" Similar code in C++ would look like this :

```
// #include <cstdio> // <== this is a "C" header file 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector> //C++ resizable array
#include <sstream>

// using namespace std; <== NO do not do this

// model players to avoid having "parallel" arrays
// these kind of data structures will get out of sync due to bugs
struct Player
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned int score; // if score can never be negative make it an unsigned int
};

bool compare_by_score(const Player& lhs, const Player& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.score < rhs.score);
}

std::vector<Player> load_players(std::istream& input)
{
    std::vector<Player> players;
    std::string name;
    unsigned int score;
    
    while ( input >> name >> score )
    {
        players.push_back(Player{name,score});
    }

    return players;
}

// make it easy to write information on a player to any outputstream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Player& player)
{
    os << player.name << " " << player.score;
    return os;
}

int main() 
{
  // FILE *filePr;  // In C++ do NOT use raw owning pointers. Whenever an error occurs you have a dangling resource (lookup RAII)
  
  //std::istream input{"example.txt"};
  std::istringstream input{"Auden 12\nJames 9\nGibson 3"}; // for testing don't use a file
  auto players = load_players(input);

  // don't use index based for loops if you don't need to
  // use range based for loops

  for(const auto& player : players)
  {
      std::cout << player << "\n"; // this works because of operator<< defined earlier
  }
 
  // with the use of std vector you can also start using other stuff from the standard library
  // like finding the high score
  auto player_it = std::max_element(players.begin(),players.end(),compare_by_score);
  std::cout << "\nHigh score : " << (*player_it) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```